# How to fetch NULL from dbs

Tags: php, mysql

If I fetch result from MySQL database with *NULL* value then PHP working with it as *string* value. Test for null value is return me FALSE and *echo* return **NULL**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `activation`
  FROM `authentication`
  WHERE `mail`=?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $mail);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if (is_null($result)) {
  echo 'is NULL';
} else echo 'not NULL';
```

return from this example will be **not NULL** but I want to get **is NULL**

Comment: Why do you need to know that it's specifically null? Why not just use `empty($result)` instead?

Comment: because empty() is return FALSE too.

Comment: Er... then what does it contain?

Comment: What you can't understand? I need return TRUE from call empty() for NULL value because NULL is empty value.

Comment: `empty(null)` returns true. If your call to `empty($result)` is returning false, then $result is not null as you claim. So, what is it? Does it actually contain the *string* "NULL"? Use `var_dump($result)` to see it.

Comment: YES this is it. It's in my first post that $result is string value and I can't fetch it in right value

Comment: If this query is returning string "NULL" to PHP then you must have string "NULL" in your database and *NOT* true NULL. Perhaps you have inadvertently quoted NULL in the DEFAULT clause of your table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with value saved in database. I do UPDATE record and now it's working.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT `activation`
  FROM `authentication`
  WHERE `mail` ";

if (!is_null($mail) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $sql .= " = ?";
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $mail);
}
else {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $sql .= " ?";
    $stmt->bind_param('s', 'IS NULL');
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if (is_null($result)) {
  echo 'is NULL';
} else echo 'not NULL';
```

If I am not mistaking a null value concatenated to a string produces no output, so you have to explicitly say IS NULL

In addition

the statements in mysql are not identical

```
select * from config where description = null;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
select * from config where description is null;
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm unsure whether concatenating onto the return of a function is good practice, can you provide a reference?

Comment: I want to test $result not $mail because my $mail variable for stmt is not null but my result from `activation` can be NULL

Comment: try defining $result = null; before passing it to bind_result

Comment: when you say null do you mean a result with no records returned or the actual column value is null?

Comment: there is a difference between a column with an empty string and a column that contains a null value

Comment: I mean result with column value is `NULL`. Problem is that it will return string type value with 'NULL' record